# How can I get the jobid number of a job submitted on slurm using perl script?

Tags: perl, slurm

I have two jobs, jobA.sh and jobB.sh. I want jobB.sh to start after jobA.sh has successfully completed. For this I have to get the jobid number of the jobA.sh. But the following part of my code is problematic. My code gives the following error. That error means the jobB.sh doesn't start. The code couldn't get the jobid number of the jobA.sh. How can I get the jobid number of the jobA.sh?

Error:

> Submitted batch job 298784 sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed:
>   Job dependency problem

The code submits the jobA.sh correctly but it gives above error for the jobB.sh.

```
my $jobidA=0;
my $jobs = "sbatch jobA.sh";
system $jobs || die "Error:\n$jobs\nerror";
# I think the following line captures jobid?
($jobs =~ /^Submitted batch job (\d+)/); 
# And the following line stores jobid?
my $jobidA = $1;

my $jobs2 = "$path/jobB.sh";
my $jobs2 = "sbatch --dependency=afterok:$jobidA $jobB.sh";
system $jobs2 || die "Error:\n$jobs2\nerror";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the following code parts separately. They are OK. You can use them.

If the jobB is dependent on the jobA, you can add the following part to your code. It was tested.

```
my $jobid1 = 0;
my $jobs = `sbatch jobA.sh`;
$jobs =~ /^Submitted batch job (\d+)/; 
$jobid1 = $1;

my $jobs2 = "$path/jobB.sh";
my $jobs2 = "sbatch --dependency=afterok:$jobid1 $jobB.sh";
system $jobs2 || die "Error:\n$jobs2\nerror";
```

The following example has three jobs that are dependent on the previously submitted job. This was tested too.

```
my $jobid1 = 0;
my $jobs = `sbatch jobA.sh`;
$jobs =~ /^Submitted batch job (\d+)/; 
$jobid1 = $1;

my $jobs2 = "$path/jobB.sh";
my $jobs2 = `sbatch --dependency=afterok:$jobid1 $jobB.sh`;
$jobs =~ /^Submitted batch job (\d+)/; 
$jobid2 = $1;

my $jobs3 = "$path/jobC.sh";
my $jobs3 = "sbatch --dependency=afterok:$jobid2 $jobC.sh";
system $jobs3 || die "Error:\n$jobs3\nerror";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the output of the sbatch command you can not use system but have to use backticks to capture the output. Use (untested code):

```
my $jobidA=0;
my $jobs = "sbatch jobA.sh";
my $output = `$jobs`
($jobs =~ /^Submitted batch job (\d+)/); 

$jobidA = $1;

my $jobs2 = "$path/jobB.sh";
$jobs2 = "sbatch --dependency=afterok:$jobidA $jobB.sh";
system $jobs2 || die "Error:\n$jobs2\nerror";
```